# How to make an MCPE server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I would like to create my own server so that my brother and I can play together. I have tried writing in seeds and it won't work for me. How can I create my own server?

Comment: If you're just playing with your brother, I would recommend trying a LAN server.

Answer (score -2):

You can only make multiplayer games if you have the paid for version.

Comment: Not true. The way s/he specified is not how creating servers work, so this is not the answer.